# What is the verb form of "Enjambment"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, vocabulary

I wish to say in a poetry commentary something like:

> These two **enjambing** lines demonstrate...

I know *enjambing* is not a real word, but I wish for something to substitute.

Comment: Can't you just refer to *the enjambment*?

Comment: @Charon: I can, but it personally would sound more _satisfying_ if I could possibly say it with a verb. So far, I am indeed just referring to _the enjambment_ . I hope there is an option though!

Comment: I've encountered *enjambed* lines, but never *enjambing*. We attribute enjambment to the poet, not the lines.

Comment: Obviously, "enjambmentizing". (Except in the UK it would be "enjambmentising".)

Comment: Another term is 'run-on', as in "These two **run-on** lines demonstrate...".

Comment: These two conjoined lines...

Comment: I think *enjambed* works fine in this case. It's even in [dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enjambed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct verb form, I think you could use some alternative expressions like *link or overlap* depending on the context. In the sentence you suggest you need an adjective rather than a verb:

[Enjambment](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=enjambment):

> - also enjambement, 1837, from French enjambement or from enjamb (c. 1600), ***from French enjamber "to stride over,***" from en- (see en- (1)) + jambe "leg" (see jamb).

***[Enjambment](http://literarydevices.net/enjambment/)***

> - derived from a French word enjambment, means to step over or put legs across. In poetry it means moving over from one line to another without a terminating punctuation mark. It can be defined as a thought or sense, phrase or clause in a line of poetry that does not come to an end at the line break but moves over to the next line. In simple words, it is the running on of a sense from one couplet or line to the next without a major pause or syntactical break.

(literarydevices.net)

Comment: Ah. So continuing a single phrase over two lines of poetry is analogically equivalent to getting one's leg over? Trust the French to come up with that idea :)

Comment: So the verb participle you are perhaps seeking is *overstepping*. *These two overstepping lines demonstrate...*

Comment: enjamber is not stride over. It means one leg comes after another. So, if you enjamber a creek, you jump over it.

Comment: @Lambie: From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/stride): stride across/over *no object* Cross (an obstacle) with one long step.
‘by giving a little leap she could stride across like a grown-up'.

Comment: @PeterShor That's the funny thing, enjamber does not contain the idea of a long step. It's the idea of a single step OR the idea of throwing one's leg over something in order to jump or leap over it, like a railing. Elle a enjambé le ruisseau: She jumped across, leapt across or hopped across the stream. Elle a enjambé la rambarde: She went over(hopped over) the railing.  OR franchir un seuil d'une seule **enjambée**=tp cross the threshold with one stride. une enjambée can be in one stride.

Comment: @Lambie: It seems like there's not one word which will translate all uses of *enjamber*, but I think *stride over* would be a perfectly good translation of many uses of *enjamber*. Now, we can argue about whether, metaphorically, you stride, leap, jump, or hurdle across the break between lines in poems.

Comment: @PeterShor The issue with stride over is that it evokes walking or moving or crossing **purposefully**. And enjamber, the verb, simply does not. I was not addressing the use in poetry of enjambement. To complete a line grammatically after a line break. The image enjamber something: one leg on one side of a rift, opening, barrier, etc. and the other on the other side. So,in poetry, it's **as if** the poet has a leg on each side of the line break, as it were.

Answer (score 1):

Try straddle. Like "the phrase straddles two lines." Enjambment comes from the french word for straddling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think enjambment get used much outside poetry, and then only in discussion of ideas and images within the structure of the poem.

Outside of that, you could use "these **adjoining** lines demonstrate..."